# Does anyone have information on using right circular cones to solve problems about circles in the plane?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, math-history

I heard about this from a college professor but haven't ever been able to find any other mention of it. I remember it being called "La Guerre" geometry, I could be wrong there.

The story was that a French mathematician was taken as a POW in some war (no idea which one, but pre-WWII anyway and possibly hundreds of years before that). He was bored and passed the time doing geometry in the dirt on the floor of his cell. He noticed that if you have circle problems in the Euclidean plane you can sometimes solve them more easily by turning the problem into a 3-space problem with cones instead.

The general idea is that each circle is the base of a right circular cone (h=r). Then the vertex of each cone (r units above the center of the circle) acts as a stand-in for the whole initial circle.

Something like that anyway.

There is, confusingly, also a mathematician named Laguerre, but what I can find on him doesn't seem to be quite what I'm talking about.

In any case, I'd love to know more about it all. I remember we did some very cool proofs using this method and I just haven't been able to coax Google into finding what I need. Hopefully I'll have more luck here.

Comment: Can you provide a statement and the proof using this method? It might help the community determine what type of geometry is going on more easily.

Comment: Is it possible that you're thinking of Girard Desargues? I don't see a POW connection, but Desargues discussed projectively-invariant properties of conic sections. Here's an interesting-looking paper: ["Desargues' *Brouillon Project* and the *Conics* of Apollonius" (PDF)](http://www.jphogendijk.nl/publ/Desargues2.pdf)

Comment: You might also consider asking about this on the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange.

Comment: From Wikipedia: [Jean-Victor Poncelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Victor_Poncelet) "Russians held him as a prisoner of war and confined him at Saratov" is a founder of projective geometry. Perhaps he is the one.

Comment: @Somos: Poncelet certainly fits the description better than Desargues. Incidentally, Google Books has [*Traité des propriétés projectives des figures*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Traité_des_propriétés_projectives_des.html?id=82ISAAAAIAAJ), the work Poncelet wrote while imprisoned.